# Delete records in Cassandra table based on time range

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I have a Cassandra table with schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTable(
    documentId text,
    sequenceNo bigint,
    messageData blob,
    clientId text
    PRIMARY KEY(documentId, sequenceNo))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY(sequenceNo DESC);
```

Is there a way to delete the records which were inserted between a given time range? I know internally Cassandra must be using some timestamp to track the insertion time of each record, which would be used by features like TTL.

Since there is no explicit column for insertion timestamp in the given schema, is there a way to use the implicit timestamp or is there any better approach?

There is never any update to the records after insertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an interesting question...

All columns that aren't part of the primary key have so-called WriteTime that could be retrieved using the `writetime(column_name)` function of CQL (**warning**: it doesn't work with collection columns, and return null for UDTs!).  But because we don't have nested queries in the CQL, you will need to write a program to fetch data, filter out entries by WriteTime, and delete entries where WriteTime is older than your threshold.  (**note** that value of `writetime` is in microseconds, not milliseconds as in CQL's `timestamp` type).

The easiest way is to use [Spark Cassandra Connector's RDD API](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md#example-using-select-to-retreive-ttl-and-timestamp), something like this:

```scala
val timestamp = someDate.toInstant.getEpochSecond * 1000L
val oldData = sc.cassandraTable(srcKeyspace, srcTable)
      .select("prk1", "prk2", "reg_col".writeTime as "writetime")
      .filter(row => row.getLong("writetime") < timestamp)
oldData.deleteFromCassandra(srcKeyspace, srcTable, 
      keyColumns = SomeColumns("prk1", "prk2"))
```

where: `prk1`, `prk2`, ... are all components of the primary key (`documentId` and `sequenceNo` in your case), and `reg_col` - any of the "regular" columns of the table that isn't collection or UDT (for example, `clientId`). It's important that list of the primary key columns in `select` and `deleteFromCassandra` was the same.

Comment: I agree with your approach, even my initial thought was also same. However, my concern is we have huge data in the DB (around 6TB across 6 nodes). I suspect it will be non-performant to initially get all records and then apply filter on the same to delete records. I was looking to avoid the first step(of getting records) to delete the data. If my understanding is correct, we will first get say 100 records and after filtering with time stamp, we have marked say 70 records which need to be deleted, then we have to fire 70 queries to DB for deletion(in worst case), right?

Comment: Spark Cassandra Connector parallelize queries by splitting them into token ranges, and process data. Spark should optimize reading & filtering of the data, so it shouldn't read all data as whole & then filter - filter should happen in parallel with reading data

Comment: Real optimization would be only if you have timestamp as first clustering column - even if you had timestamp as a separate column that isn't first clustering column, then it will work the same as I described

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Spark APIs should filter records in parallel. We are not using spark-cassandra-connector(using prepared statement, query builder) in the project, however, can you please clarify one point. Using spark APIs,  I think it should work without timestamp as an explicit column in the schema. So, when you said "Real optimization would be.....", you meant if we had timestamp in the column, then no need this spark's filter API and can be directly queried with that timestamp column, right?

Comment: There are several things here. 1) You can access `writetime` without Spark, but if you do it, then you will need to make full scan of the data and this is not so easy task if you didn't do it before - Spark will do it for you. 2) Optimization is also not related to Spark - if you have timestamp column as **first** clustering column, then filtering will happen on Cassandra side, and you won't need to read all data from Cassandra.